# SimpleLevelLoader + PhysicsEditor + AndEngine vs AndEngine-Anchor

Tags: java, android, box2d, andengine, andengine-gles-2

I'm new in "AndEngine".

started to build a game and got some conflicts,

I want to use the following extantions:

1. AndEngine-PhysicsEditor-Extension
2. AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension

I realize that the PhysicsEditor Doesn't support the AndEngine-Anchor and need the normal AndEngine.

But I want to use the following classes:
SimpleLevelLoader , EntityLoader , SimpleLevelEntityLoaderData to load the level from a XML file. that are availibe only in the AndEngine-Anchor.

Am I missing something? , How cam I resolve this conflict?

Thanks :)

Comment: Physics editor actually comes with a loader(program files) for andengine, but it is actually for the old GLES 2 version. However, it is fairly simple to edit yourself, all you really need to do is change the method names a bit in the basegameactivity class.

Comment: Ammm I need to set the engine to "GLES 2" Or "GLES 2 - Anchor"
and than edit one of them?
Didn't understand what you meant

Comment: Keep your engine as AC branch. Go to program files and find physics editor program, examples and then andengine. You should have two classes now, you need to edit the PhysicsEditorExample class so it is compatible with AC. It should be just a case of changing method names from like onLoadResources to onCreateResources etc.